Prove that there is no conformal mapping between $\mathbb{D}\setminus\{0,1/2\}$ and $\mathbb{D}\setminus\{0,1/4\}$
I have to prove that there is no conformal mapping between $\mathbb{D}\setminus\{0,1/2\}$ and $\mathbb{D}\setminus\{0,1/4\}$. I honestly have no idea. Intuitively, I guess that the problem has to do with the distances from $1/2$ and $1/4$ to zero. The usual trick to solve this problems is to suppose that there is such an isomorphism and derive a contradiction. In this case, if some isomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{D}\setminus\{0,1/2\} \rightarrow \mathbb{D}\setminus\{0,1/4\}$ existed all I can say is that it has removable singularities at $0$ and $1/2$, as the image is bounded (therefore it can't have a pole, because then it would diverge, neither an essential singularity, as the image of a punctured neighborhood is not dense). I can extend $\phi$ to make it holomorphic, but I don't know what to do with it.

After dealing with removable singularities you are talking about a univalent map from $\mathbb D$ to itself.  These functions are known to be moebius maps with a very particular form...

another hint in the same vein - once you extend to a disc self-map, it is clear that it must remain an isomorphism (so send the two omitted points in each domain to each other injectively) by looking at local behavior at $0, 1/2$ and then it must preserve the hyperbolic metric; but the hyperbolic distance (easily computed) between $0,1/2$ is different from the hyperbolic distance between $0,1.4$ (this is also reflected in the above comment or the Schwarz Pick inequality which can be used instead for either the direct or the inverse function)

Idea of the proof: As you already mentioned the easiest would be to perform a proof by contradiction in the sense that if such a map exists then it extends to a conformal map $\phi \colon \mathbb D \to \mathbb D$ and then use the specific forms of conformal maps from the unit disk to the unit disk.
Proof: Suppose that there exists a map $\phi \colon \mathbb D \setminus \{0,1/2\} \to \mathbb D \setminus \{0,1/4\}$ exists. Then since $\phi$ is bounded around every open neighborhood of $0$ and $1/2$ both are removable singularities and thus $\phi$ extends to $\phi \; \colon \mathbb D \to \mathbb D$ such that without loss of generality $\phi(0)=0$ and $\phi(1/2)=1/4$. Now since $\phi \colon \mathbb D \to \mathbb D$ is conformal it must be that
$$
\phi(z) = \lambda \frac{z-a}{1-\overline{a}z} \quad \text{ where }|a|<1 \; |\lambda| =1.
$$
Now plugging in $\phi(0)=0$ yields that $a=0$ but then $\phi(1/2)=1/4$ is impossible since $|\lambda| = 1$. The case $\phi(0)=1/4$ and $\phi(1/2)=0$ follows analogously and this finishes the proof.

Sketch of a proof: a homeomorphism of a space extends to a homeomorphism of its completion by adding its "ends" ( a topological notion). This implies that every homeomorphism of a disk without two points extends to an homeomorphism of its completion with ends, that is, the sphere.
Now assume that we have a conformal isomorphism like above, call it $f$, and $\bar f$ its extention to the ends ( $3$ of them).  Now, we cannot have $\bar f$ map to $\infty$, because of the behaviour of a holomorphic map at essential singularities ( Casorati-Weierstrass). Therefore, we get $\bar f$ maps $\{0,1/2\}$ to $\{0, 1/4\}$, so $\bar f$ is in fact holomorphic ( Riemann extension theorem). So $\bar f$ is an automorphism of the disk, and (say mapping $0$ to itself) so it cannot map $1/2$ to $1/4$.
The argument works in general for some points removed from the disk.

How does the identity function $\mathbb D\to \mathbb D$ extend to a map on the sphere?

@KentaS: the sphere would be the 1 point compactification of the disk, so $\infty\mapsto \infty$.  We could avoid the compactification with ends, and just use the classical theorems from complex analysis.
